# Prove that unitary matrices map orthonormal bases to orthonormal bases

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is as follows:
If $A$ is a unitary matrix for a a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$, where $V$ is a real euclidean space and $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of V, then show that ${Av_1,...,Av_n} is an orthonormal basis.

I know that if A is a unitary matrix that it can be diagonalized, i.e. there exists distinct linearly independent eigenvectors $x_1,...x_n$ such that P (where P is the matrix made up of the columns of the eigenvectors) is invertible such that
$AP=PD$ for some diagonal matrix $D$.

I also know that the rows and the columns of unitary matrices are orthonormal.

How can I relate these facts to the question? Thanks.

Comment: If $A$ is unitary, what can we say about $\langle Av,Aw \rangle$ and its relation to $\langle v,w\rangle$? Can you translate the statement on rows and columns of $A$ to something which can be said about $A$ and $A^*$ (and $AA^*$?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\langle A v_i, A v_j \rangle = \langle v_i, A^* A v_j \rangle = \langle v_i, I v_j \rangle = \langle v_i, v_j \rangle = 0$ for $i \neq j$ by the definition of adjoint.

Thus, $\{A v_i\}$ are a collection of orthogonal vectors. Since you have the same number of vectors as a basis and [orthogonal implies linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409810/orthogonality-and-linear-independence), this is a basis.