# If for all $i, j$, $w_j \cdot v_i=0$, then $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_r, w_1, w_2, \dots, w_r \}$ be a linearly independently.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_r\}$ be a linearly independent set of vectors in $R^d$ and $\{w_1, w_2, \dots, w_s\}$ be another linearly independent set of vectors in $R^d$. If for all $i, j$, $w_j \cdot v_i=0$, then $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_r, w_1, w_2, \dots, w_s \}$ be a linearly independently.

I try to write that for constants $c_i$: consider
$$c_1v_1+\dots+c_rv_r+c_{r+1}w_1+\dots+c_{r+s}w_s=0$$
and let product the $w_1$ for both side... But how to do the next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Orthogonality and linear independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409810/orthogonality-and-linear-independence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: take the equality

$$c_1 v_1 + \ldots + c_r v_r + c_{r+1} w_1 + \ldots + c_{r+s} w_s = 0$$

and apply the dot product with $c_1 v_1 + \ldots + c_r v_r$ to both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to go for the following simple statement first: if two subspaces are orthogonal to one another, they form a direct sum (which can be shown by showing their intersection to be of dimension$~0$). Then we have two bases of subspaces (the ones spanned by the $v$s respectively the $w$s) that form a direct sum, and it is well known that in such a situation the concatenation of these bases then is a basis for the direct sum. I'll let you fill in any details you find necessary.