# Proving the existence of specific scalars for perpendicular block vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence, orthogonality, block-matrices

$\newcommand{\ba}{\mathbf{a}}$$\newcommand{\bb}{\mathbf{b}}$$\newcommand{\bc}{\mathbf{c}}$
Given two vectors, $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^{9}, \mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^{6}$, each with a norm of $\lVert\mathbf{a}\rVert=\lVert\mathbf{b}\rVert=\sqrt{2}~$, along with nonzero scalars $c, \alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i\in\mathbb{R}$, where $i\in\{0,1,2\}$, consider the following block vectors:
$$
\mathbf{v}_0 := \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_0\ba\\
\alpha_1\bb\\
\alpha_2c\\
\end{bmatrix}~,\qquad
%
\mathbf{v}_1 := \begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0\ba\\
\beta_1\bb\\
\beta_2c\\
\end{bmatrix}~,\qquad
%
\mathbf{v}_2 := \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_0\ba\\
\gamma_1\bb\\
\gamma_2c\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm struggling to demonstrate the following:

1. The existence of nonzero values of $\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i$, with $i\in\{0,1,2\}$, that:
   1.1) make the set of vectors $\{\mathbf{v}_0, \mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2\}$ mutually perpendicular.
   1.2) satisfy the condition $\alpha_i^2+\beta_i^2+\gamma_i^2=1$
2. That any other vector, constructed similarly, such as:
   $$
   \mathbf{v}_3 :=\begin{bmatrix}
   \nu_0\ba\\
   \nu_1\bb\\
   \nu_2c\\
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
   will be linearly dependent to the set $\{\mathbf{v}_0, \mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2\}$.

Is there a way to show that that these points can be satisfied?

---

To clarify, in case I am posing a XY problem, my end goal is to demonstrate that $\mathbf{v}_0, \mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2$ can be the sole eigenvectors / singular vectors with nonzero eigenvalues, of a symmetric matrix that is formed by a linear combination of the outer products: $\mathbf{v}_0\mathbf{v}_0^\top$, $\mathbf{v}_1\mathbf{v}_1^\top$, $\mathbf{v}_2\mathbf{v}_2^\top$.

Comment: a) For nonzero vectors, 2. is a consequence of 1.1). b) Why do **all** scalars have to be nonzero, and why would "$\alpha_0 = \beta_1 = \gamma_2 = 1$, and all other coefficients zero" not be suitable for your purposes?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist thank you very much. I now understand why 1.1) implies 2.. All scalars must be nonzero to ensure that the vectors $\mathbf{v}_i$ are meaningful in my problem. This requirement also applies to the condition $\alpha_i^2 + \beta_i^2 + \gamma_i^2 = 1$. Empirically, in my problem, I have consistently observed that vectors of the form $\mathbf{v}_i$ are the singular vectors of my symmetric matrix of interest.

Comment: Consider the vectors
$
\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf a}\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
{\bf b}\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
c\\
\end{bmatrix}
$. They span a 3D subspace $U \subseteq \Bbb R^{16}$ that contains $v_0, v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$. Now, by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409810/orthogonality-and-linear-independence), the set $v_0,v_1,v_2$ is linearly independent, that is, their span $V = \langle v_0, v_1, v_2\rangle$ is 3D. But $V \subseteq U$, so we have $U = V$. In particular, $v_3$ is a linear combination of $v_0, v_1, v_2$.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the standard inner products leads to an equivalent statement: does there exist a $3\times 3$ real matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha_0\sqrt{2}&\beta_0 \sqrt{2} & \gamma_0 \sqrt{2} \\ \alpha_1\sqrt{2}&\beta_1 \sqrt{2} & \gamma_1 \sqrt{2} \\ \alpha_2&\beta_2 & \gamma_2 \end{pmatrix}$ with nonzero elements such that the diagonal elements of $M M^T$ are $2,2,1$ and $M^TM$ is a diagonal matrix?

Suppose $F$ is a symmetric matrix with nonzero elements such that $F^2$ is the identity. Such matrices exist: e.g.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}+2\right) & \frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}+2\right) & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) & \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

(I constructed this one by conjugating $\text{diag}(1,-1,1)$ with $\pi/4$ rotations in three planes.)

Then, if we take $D = \text{diag}(x,y,z)$ and $M = FD$, $M^T M$ is still diagonal, but with $x,y,z$ we can now vary the diagonal elements of $M M^T$. I didn't think much about values on the diagonal that we can get in that manner (as linear combinations with positive coefficients), and whether we can *always* get $2,2,1$, but at least for this specific $F$ Mathematica gives $x^2 = 2$, $y^2 = (9+4\sqrt2)/7$, $z^2 = 4(3-\sqrt2)/7$. So the claim is true.

**Note**: this problem might have a substantially easier solution.

---

**Edit.** 1) Yes, it indeed assumes $c = 1$, sorry... For some reason I missed $c$ completely, so the last row of $M$ should be $\alpha_2 c, \beta_2 c, \gamma_2 c$.

2), 3) With the corrected $M$, we have $M M^T = \begin{pmatrix}2(\alpha_0^2+\beta_0^2+\gamma_0^2) & \ldots & \ldots\\ \ldots & 2(\alpha_1^2+\beta_1^2+\gamma_1^2) & \ldots\\ \ldots&\ldots & c^2(\alpha_2^2+\beta_2^2+\gamma_2^2) \end{pmatrix}$ and
$M^T M = \begin{pmatrix}
\ldots & \alpha_2 \beta_2 c^2+2 \alpha_0 \beta_0+2 \alpha_1 \beta_1 & \alpha_2 \gamma_2 c^2+2 \alpha_0 \gamma_0+2 \alpha_1 \gamma_1 \\
 \alpha_2 \beta_2 c^2+2 \alpha_0 \beta_0+2 \alpha_1 \beta_1 & \ldots & \beta_2 \gamma_2 c^2+2 \beta_0 \gamma_0+2 \beta_1 \gamma_1 \\
 \alpha_2 \gamma_2 c^2+2 \alpha_0 \gamma_0+2 \alpha_1 \gamma_1 & \beta_2 \gamma_2 c^2+2 \beta_0 \gamma_0+2 \beta_1 \gamma_1 & \ldots \\
\end{pmatrix}$

The diagonal elements of $MM^T$ are scalar multiples of LHS in the conditions $\alpha_i^2 + \beta_i^2 + \gamma_i^2 = 1$, and the off-diagonal elements of $M^T M$ are the LHS of the orthogonality relations for $v_0, v_1, v_2$.

The problem is, after I reintroduce $c$, the equations on $x,y,z$ (that were $a,b,c$ in my older revision; changed notation to not confuse with OP) need not have real roots. For my $F$, the roots are all real if $|c| \in (3-2\sqrt2,2+2\sqrt2) \approx (0.17,4.83)$. This is definitely not the general case, and I'm not sure whether we can get arbitrarily close to $0$ or to $+\infty$ when varying $F$.

Comment: Your answer is exceptional, thank you very much for your help. If I may, I'd like to ask a few questions to fully understand it: 
1) Does this solution assume $c^2=1$? If so, it works perfectly for my case as well.
2) Can we limit our search to a 3x3 matrix $M$, since $MM^T = M^TM$ contains the results of all inner products $\mathbf{v}_i\mathbf{v}_j$?
3) Does this solution satisfy the condition $\alpha_i^2 + \beta_i^2 + \gamma_i^2 = 1$? If it doesn't, I understand that this might be addressed by selecting specific values for $a, b, c$.

Comment: @gtg You're right, I forgot about $c$... Please see the **Edit** section.

Comment: No need to say sorry at all. I see, thank you for the additional help! :)